# Blender is only Rendering the first frame of my animation for Smoke

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So I used blender cycle render to render a quick smoke effect.  I only scaled up and used adaptive domain and high resolution.  When I render, I only get one frame!  I rendered as a avi raw file.  [image]

Here is the screen shot of the settings[image]

Comment: Did you render using the animation button?

Comment: Yes, I did, this is a example where I rendered as a image or still